# Is There A Word For Converger?

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary

It seems that "Converger" is not even a word. However, I cannot express my question in any other way. I looked on the Internet with no luck.

I need a word or an official idiom to express an adjective of a person who can converge the different points of view and come up with a solution that makes everyone happy.

**Is there such a word?**

Comment: **Converger** [is certainly a word](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=converger).  However, it doesn't really mean what you want.

Comment: If the parties are fighting then _peacemaker_ would work.

Answer (score 1):

[**Mediator**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mediator) is probably the best:

> One who negotiates between parties seeking mutual agreement.

It carries the connotation of a third party who tries to find a middle ground between two other parties, as opposed to simply **negotiator** which could mean someone working for the benefit of one side or the other.

**Evaluator** or **arbitrator** are similar terms you can look up.